# HTML Email: formatting disappears in outlook after bolded word

Tags: html, outlook, format, html-email

I have a paragraph with inline styling, set up as a list using 
 tags. One of the words on each line is bolded, and after the bolded word the font for the rest of the paragraph shrinks when sent through outlook.

Example here:

```
    <p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;"><strong>Hong Kong</strong> &ndash; Monday, Oct. 15<br />
<strong>Macau</strong> &ndash; Tuesday, Oct. 16<br />
<strong>Guangzhou</strong> &ndash; Wednesday, Oct. 17<br />
<strong>Shanghai</strong> &ndash; Friday, Oct. 19<br />
<strong>Chengdu</strong> &ndash; Monday, Oct. 22<br />
<strong>Wuhan</strong> &ndash; Wednesday, Oct. 24<br />
<strong>Taipei</strong> &ndash; Friday, Oct. 26<br />
<strong>Tokyo</strong> &ndash; Monday, Oct. 29<br />
    </p>
```

I have a similar problem in another paragraph, this time the font shrinks after a linked email address. Example:

```
    <p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;">
Jane Smith, <a href="mailto:jane@smith.org" title="mailto:jane@smith.org" class="" target="_blank"mailto:jane@smith.org</a>, is a professional and entrepreneur who knows California from her past work in Los Angeles. She is a certified  Diploma holder and has managed two businesses in the Roppongi neighborhood in Tokyo.
</p>
```

The issue appears when I insert the dreamweaver file as text into Outlook 2016 (method for sending for review around the office). It looks fine when sent from MailChimp but reappears when forwarded, which is an issue for us.

Any ideas/workarounds much appreciated.

I solved the list problem by turning it into a bulleted list. I used the  tag, which Outlook ignores, but I can live with that.

The other issue is still there. I did many tests, to try and see why when I changed the text (to make this company newsletter more anonymous in a public forum) the erratic formatting disappeared. I recreated the item, tried removing the image copied the item so I could see side by side what was happening. Here are some images of two tests side by side and also the code, which was unchanged--I changed the text in one spot.
[On the right is the problem formatting, on the left it has miraculously disappeared. The only thing I changed was the name to Jane Smith and I added the photo back in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw6le.jpg)
Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style>
li {
    text-indent: -1em; /* Normalise space between bullets and text */
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]>
<style type="text/css">
body, table, td {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>News Briefs: Proposed Cannabis Regulations Published</title>
<style type="text/css">
.ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}
.ExternalClass {width: 100%;}

body {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 margin-top: 0px;
}
a { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
a:link {
 color: #004a80;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-color: #004a80;
}
a:visited {
 color: #004a80;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-color: #004a80;

}
a:hover {
 color: #004a80;
 border-bottom-style: dotted;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-color: #004a80;
}
h1 {
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-style:bold;
  color:#f68a33;
  margin-top:20px;
}
h2 {
 color: #333333; 
 font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
 font-size: 26px; 
 line-height: 32px;
 letter-spacing: 0px; 
 font-weight:100;
}
h3,h4,h5,h6, {
 color:#444444;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 23px;
 letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
p {color:#444444;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.preheader{color: #808283;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
 font-size: 12px; 
 line-height: 17px;
 letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}
.volumedate{color: #808283;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
 font-size: 12px; 
 line-height: 17px;
 letter-spacing: 0.01em;
        text-align: center;
}
a.norule {
 color: #000000;
 border-bottom-style: none;
 border-bottom-width: 0px;
 border-bottom-color: #000000;
}
a:hover.norule {
 color: #000000;
 border-bottom-style: none;
 border-bottom-width: 0px;
 border-bottom-color: #000000;
}
.appleLinksWhite, .appleLinksWhite a {color: #fffef1 !important; text-decoration: none;} 
.appleLinksBlack, .appleLinksBlack a {color: #444444 !important; text-decoration: none;}
.appleLinksCalendar, .appleLinksCalendar a {color: #f68a33 !important; text-decoration: none;}

span.yshortcuts { color:#000; background-color:none; border:none;}
span.yshortcuts:hover,
span.yshortcuts:active,
span.yshortcuts:focus {color:#000; background-color:none; border:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 0px;">
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="ffffff" style=""><tr><td>
<table width="650" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#fffef1"><tr><td width="650">&nbsp;

    <table width="630" height="" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" bgcolor="#fffef1"><tr>
<td align="center"><span class="preheader" style="color: #808283; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 17px; letter-spacing: 0.01em;">U.S. Now Ranks Third in World Wine Production</span></td>
 </tr></table>
<!-- Masthead Goes Here -->
<center><table border="0" bgcolor="#000000" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="650" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
<tr><td valign="top" align="left"><img alt="Logo" src="http://www.wineinstitute.org/images/NB/images/NewsBriefs-Logo-650.png" border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" width="650" height="110" style="display:block;" /></td></tr></table></center>
<!-- VOLUME/DATE MODULE STARTS --> 
<table border="0" align="center" width="650" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#fffef1">
<tr>
<td>
<span style="height: 2px;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="650" height="2" /></span>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" style="border-top: solid 2px #fffef1;"><span class="volumedate" style="color: #808283; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 17px; letter-spacing: 0.01em; text-align: center;"><center>
       Volume 26, Number 2 | July 18, 2018
       </center></span></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<!--TOC -->
<table width="630" border="0" bgcolor="#fffef1">
<tr>
<td width="166" valign="top">
      <div style="height: 10; width: 166;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="166" height="10" style="display: block;" /></div>

     <div style="height: 83; width: 166;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.InThisIssue.jpg" width="166" height="83" alt="In This Issue" style="display: block;" /></div>&nbsp;</td>

        <td width="464" valign="top">

              <ul>
                <li style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 5px;">Vintner Tour to China & Japan: Register by July 23</li>
                <li style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;">New Representatives Appointed</li>
            </ul>

        </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="left">
<span style="height: 5px;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="615" height="5" /></span>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>


<!-- 01NEWS MODULE STARTS--><table width="615" align="center" bgcolor="#fffef1">
<tr><td style="border-top: 1px dotted #A7A9AC;" align="left">
<h1 style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: 2px; font-style: bold; color: #f68a33; margin-top: 20px;">INTERNATIONAL MARKETING</h1>
<h2 style="color: #333333; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: 26px; line-height: 32px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 100;">Register for California Wines Vintner Tour <br />
to China & Japan by July 23</h2>
<table width="250" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0pt none; margin: 0 10px 2px 10px;"><tr><td>
<img alt="http://www.discovercaliforniawines.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/TradeTasting-Macao-2017_300x249.jpg" src="http://www.discovercaliforniawines.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/TradeTasting-Macao-2017_300x249.jpg" width="250" height="208" />
</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;"><em>2017 Trade Tasting in Macao</em></td></tr></table>
<p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;"><a href="https://app.bottlebooks.me/app/calwine/china.html" title="https://app.bottlebooks.me/app/calwine/china.html" target="_blank">Registration is open</a> for the California Wines Vintner Tour to China and Japan scheduled for Oct. 15-29. Wineries must be members of the California Wine Export program and register by 5 p.m., July 23. China is one of the fastest growing wine markets in the world and will soon be second only to the U.S. in value; U.S. wine exports to China and Hong Kong were up 10% in 2017 to $197 million. 
</p><p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;">The tour offers seminars and tastings for consumers and trade at the following stops:

    <ul style="list-style-type: none">
    <li style="list-style-type: none; color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><strong>Hong Kong</strong> &ndash; Monday, Oct. 15</li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none; color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><strong>Macau</strong> &ndash; Tuesday, Oct. 16</li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none; color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><strong>Guangzhou</strong> &ndash; Wednesday, Oct. 17</li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none; color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><strong>Shanghai</strong> &ndash; Friday, Oct. 19</li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none; color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><strong>Chengdu</strong> &ndash; Monday, Oct. 22</li><li style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><strong>Wuhan</strong> &ndash; Wednesday, Oct. 24</li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none; color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><strong>Taipei</strong> &ndash; Friday, Oct. 26</li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none; color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><strong>Tokyo</strong> &ndash; Monday, Oct. 29</li>
    </ul>
<p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;">Contact the Asia Director with questions. To register for California Wine Export Program membership, contact Membership.</p>
</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left">
<span style="height: 5px;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="615" height="5" /></span>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<!-- NEWS MODULE ENDS -->

<!-- 01NEWS MODULE STARTS --><table width="615" align="center" bgcolor="#fffef1">
<tr><td style="border-top: 1px dotted #A7A9AC;" align="left">
<h1 style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: 2px; font-style: bold; color: #f68a33; margin-top: 20px;">INTERNATIONAL MARKETING</h1>
<h2 style="color: #333333; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: 26px; line-height: 32px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 100;">Wine Institute Appoints New Japan Team</h2>
<table width="300" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0pt none; margin: 0 10px 0 10px;"><tr><td>
<img alt="New Reps" src="http://www.discovercaliforniawines.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/NewJapanReps_300x220.jpg" width="300" height="220" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;"><em>L-R: Madoka Ogiya and Hiro
Tejima</em></td></tr></table>
<p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;">Wine Institute has appointed the Nihon-Ad, Inc. agency as its new representative office in Japan, with Madoka Ogiya and Hiro Tejima acting as the joint Trade Directors for Japan. 
</p><p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;">Jane Smith, <a href="mailto:mogiya@wineinstitute.org" title="mailto:mogiya@wineinstitute.org" class="" target="_blank">jsmith@wineinstitute.org</a>, is a wine professional and entrepreneur who knows California from her past work for Japan Airlines in Los Angeles. She is a certified WSET Diploma holder and has managed two wine bars in the Roppongi neighborhood in Tokyo. 
</p><p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;">Hiro Tejima, <a href="mailto:htejima@wineinstitute.org" title="mailto:htejima@wineinstitute.org" class="" target="_blank">htejima@wineinstitute.org</a>, graduated from Claremont McKenna College in Los Angeles and worked as a management consultant with PwC in Tokyo. Mr. Tejima has 10 years’ experience in category promotion of wine, ranging from trade and consumer tastings to running wine education programs and seminars, most recently as Wine Australia’s regional director for Asia Pacific. 
</p><p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;">Nihon-Ad is a creative agency founded in Tokyo in 1969 with experience in trade associations, food service, luxury auto brands, government and embassy offices and other clients.

</p>

 </td></tr>
<tr><td align="left">
<span style="height: 5px;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="615" height="5" /></span>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<!-- NEWS MODULE ENDS -->

<!-- 01NEWS MODULE STARTS --><table width="615" align="center" bgcolor="#fffef1">
<tr><td style="border-top: 1px dotted #A7A9AC;" align="left"><h1 style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: 2px; font-style: bold; color: #f68a33; margin-top: 20px;">INTERNATIONAL MARKETING</h1>
  <h2 style="color: #333333; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: 26px; line-height: 32px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 100;">Wine Institute Appoints New Japan Team</h2>
<table width="300" align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0pt none; margin: 0 10px 0 10px;"><tr><td>
<img alt="New Reps" src="http://www.discovercaliforniawines.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/NewJapanReps_300x220.jpg" width="300" height="220" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;"><em>L-R: Madoka Ogiya and Hiro
Tejima</em></td></tr></table>
<p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;">Wine Institute has appointed the Nihon-Ad, Inc. agency as its new representative office in Japan, with Madoka Ogiya and Hiro Tejima acting as the joint Trade Directors for Japan.
</p>
<p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;">
Madoka Ogiya, <a href="mailto:mogiya@wineinstitute.org" title="mogiya@wineinstitute.org" class="" target="_blank">mogiya@wineinstitute.org</a>, is a wine professional and entrepreneur who knows California from her past work for Japan Airlines in Los Angeles. She is a certified WSET Diploma holder and has managed two wine bars in the Roppongi neighborhood in Tokyo.
</p>
<p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;">
Hiro Tejima, <a href="mailto:htejima.org" title="mailto:htejima.org" class="" target="_blank">htejima.org</a>, , graduated from Claremont McKenna College in Los Angeles and worked as a management consultant with PwC in Tokyo. Mr. Tejima has 10 years&rsquo; experience in
category promotion of wine, ranging from trade and consumer tastings to running wine education programs and seminars, most recently as Wine Australia&rsquo;s regional director for Asia Pacific.
</p><p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 10px;">
Nihon-Ad is a creative agency founded in Tokyo in 1969 with experience in trade associations, food service, luxury auto brands, government and embassy offices and
other clients.
</p>

 </td></tr>
<tr><td align="left">
<span style="height: 5px;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="615" height="5" /></span>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<!-- NEWS MODULE ENDS -->



<a name="calendar" id="calendar" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" href="#"></a>

  <!-- CALENDAR STARTS --> 
<table width="615" align="center" border="0" bgcolor="#fffef1">
<tr><td colspan="3" align="left" style="border-top: 1px dotted #A7A9AC;"><span style="height: 40;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="615" height="40" style="display: block;"></span></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" align="left"><span style="height: 33;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.Calendar.jpg" width="339" height="33" style="display: block;"></span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><span style="height: 20;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="130" height="20" style="display: block;"></span></td>
  <td align="left"><span style="height: 20;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="10" height="10" style="display: block;"></span></td>
  <td align="left"><span style="height: 20;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="475" height="20" style="display: block;"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
  <td align="right" style="border-top: 1px solid #A7A9AC;"><span style="color: #004a80; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: 32px; line-height: 50px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 100;">2018</span></td>
  <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>


<tr valign="top">
<td align="right" style="border-top: 1px solid #A7A9AC;"><p style="color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><span class="calendar">July 24</span></p></td>
  <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top"><p style="color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><a href="https://sustainablewinegrowing.us10.list-manage.com/track/click?u=2cff3f94229ec1de06fa0e504&id=9b0ff8bb77&e=5d73dbd0d2" title="https://sustainablewinegrowing.us10.list-manage.com/track/click?u=2cff3f94229ec1de06fa0e504&id=9b0ff8bb77&e=5d73dbd0d2" class="" target="_blank">Sustainable Winegrowing for Ag Professionals</a>, 9:00 a.m.-2:30 p.m., University of California Davis. 
</p></td></tr>

<tr valign="top">
<td align="right" style="border-top: 1px solid #A7A9AC;"><p style="color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><span class="calendar">July 27</span></p></td>
  <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top"><p style="color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><a href="https://sustainablewinegrowing.us10.list-manage.com/track/click?u=2cff3f94229ec1de06fa0e504&id=a7db594742&e=5d73dbd0d2" title="https://sustainablewinegrowing.us10.list-manage.com/track/click?u=2cff3f94229ec1de06fa0e504&id=a7db594742&e=5d73dbd0d2" class="" target="_blank">Sustainable Winegrowing Field Day</a>, 10-11:30 a.m., Sonoma. 
</p></td></tr>

<tr valign="top">
<td align="right" style="border-top: 1px solid #A7A9AC;"><p style="color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><span class="calendar">Dec. 2-4</span></p></td>
  <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top"><p style="color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;">Winter Board Meeting, The Inn at Spanish Bay
</p></td></tr>

 <tr valign="top">
  <td align="right" style="border-top: 1px solid #A7A9AC;"><span style="color: #004a80; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: 32px; line-height: 50px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 100;">2019</span></td>
  <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
<td align="right" style="border-top: 1px solid #A7A9AC;"><p style="color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><span class="calendar">March 11-12</span></p></td>
  <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top"><p style="color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;">Sacramento Board Meeting 
</p></td></tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td align="right" style="border-top: 1px solid #A7A9AC;"><p style="color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;"><span class="calendar">June 9-11</span></p></td>
  <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top"><p style="color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; letter-spacing: 0.05em;">85th Annual Membership and Board of Directors Meeting, TBD 
</p></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="3" align="left" style="border-top: 1px dotted #A7A9AC;"><span style="height: 5;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="615" height="5"></span></td></tr></table>
<!-- CALENDAR ENDS -->
<table width="600px"  align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;">
                            <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;"  align="center">
                                    <center><a  class="norule" href="http://www.facebook.com/CaliforniaWines"><img alt="Facebook" src="http://www.wineinstitute.org/images/NB/images/facebook-icon-c.png" border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <a  class="norule" href="http://twitter.com/CalifWines_US"><img alt="Twitter" src="http://www.wineinstitute.org/images/NB/images/twitter-icon-c.png" border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <a  class="norule" href="https://www.pinterest.com/californiawines/"><img alt="Pinterest" src="http://www.wineinstitute.org/images/NB/images/pinterest-icon-c.png" border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                   <a  class="norule" href="https://www.instagram.com/california.wines/"><img alt="Instagram" src="http://international.discovercaliforniawines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Instagram_circular.png" border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <a  class="norule" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/wineinstitute"><img alt="YouTube" src="http://www.wineinstitute.org/images/NB/images/youtube-icon-c.png" border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" /></a></center>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

<!-- LOGO -->
<!-- SIGN UP/MEMBER MODULE STARTS --><table width="616px" height="" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Table_01" bgcolor="#fffef1">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<br /><div style="height: 94px;"><a class="norule" href="http://www.wineinstitute.org/" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #000000; border-bottom-style: none; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-bottom-color: #000000;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.Logo.jpg" width="120" height="94" border="0" /></a></div>   
    <br />
</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>
      <table width="615" align="center" bgcolor="#fffef1">
          <tr><td align="center"><p style="color:#444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-style:italic; font-size: 10px; line-height: 11px; letter-spacing: 0.00em; margin-bottom: 10px;">Wine Institute prohibits discrimination in its programs on the basis of race, color, national origin, sex, religion, age, disability and marital or familial status. Persons with disabilities who require alternative means of communication of program information (Braille, large print, audiotape, etc.) should contact <a href="mailto:communications@wineinstitute.org%20" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">communications@wineinstitute.org </a></p>
              </td></tr></table>

      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- SIGN UP/MEMBER MODULE STARTS --> 

<center>
<table width="616px" align="center" border="0" bgcolor="#fffef1">
<tr align="center" valign="top">
  <td><h1 style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: 2px; font-style: bold; color: #f68a33; margin-top: 20px;">SIGN UP FOR E-MAIL DELIVERY</h1><p>
    Contact Wine Institute at <a href="mailto:communications@wineinstitute.org">communications@wineinstitute.org</a></p></td></tr>
<tr align="center" valign="top">
  <td><h1 style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px; letter-spacing: 2px; font-style: bold; color: #f68a33; margin-top: 20px;">MEMBERS-ONLY WEB SITE</h1>
<p>To sign up for the Wine Institute Members&rsquo; Site, go to <a href="http://members.wineinstitute.org">http://members.wineinstitute.org</a> and click on &quot;Register&quot;</p> </td>
</tr>



</table>
</center>
<!-- SIGN UP/MEMBER MODULE ENDS --> 


</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>

<table width="650" height="" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td align="center">
<div style="height: 20px;"><img src="https://www.wineinstitute.org/files/WI.yellow.jpg" width="650" height="20" style="display: block;" /></div>

    </td>
 </tr></table>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Top one looks fine to me.
In the second example, the `a` tag isn't closed properly after the `target` attribute.
should probably be like this:
`<a href="mailto:jane@smith.org" title="mailto:jane@smith.org" class="" target="_blank">jane@smith.org</a>`

Comment: Thanks, I think that was me not copying code properly. Interestingly, when I changed the name to Jane Smith, it worked fine for me too. Which doesn't follow any code logic I know of...

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine in Outlook. Post the rest of the HTML code so we can get an idea of the issue.

Comment: Hi, see above edited question with additional info and code sample

Comment: Outlook is not the best way to send html emails for review unless you are only viewing them using Outlook. Email clients like Outlook, Gmail and others will strip out CSS and change code it doesn't support. Try sending with an external service like http://putsmail.com, which is free.